# Best way to implement binary serial protocol in C++

Tags: c++, protocols

I'm implementing a serial binary protocol with C++ as following format:

```
| sync word (0xAA) | sync word (0xBB) | message length (2 bytes) | device id (4 bytes) | message type (1 byte) | timestamp (4 bytes) | payload (N bytes) | crc (2 bytes) |
```

For binary operation, I can only come up C-style way. For example, use `memcpy` to extract each field with pre-defined offset:

```
void Parse(string data) {
  bool found_msg_head = false;
  int i=0;
  for (; I<data.size()-1; i++) {
    if (data[i] == 0xAA && data[i+1] == 0xBB) {
      found_msg_head = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (found_msg_head) {
    uint16_t msg_length;
    uint32_t device_id;
    // declare fields ...

    memcpy(&msg_length, data.c_str()+i+2, 2);
    memcpy(&device_id, data.c_str()+i+4, 4);
    // memcpy to each field ...

    // memcpy crc and validate...
  }
}

void SendMsg(const MyMsg& msg)
{
    const uint16_t msg_len = sizeof(msg) + 16;
    const uint32_t dev_id = 0x01
    const uint32_t timestamp = (uint32_t)GetCurrentTimestamp();
    const uint8_t msg_type = 0xAB;

    char buf[msg_len];

    buf[0] = 0xAA;
    buf[1] = 0xBB;
    memcpy(buf + 2, &msg_len, sizeof(msg_len));
    memcpy(buf + 4, &dev_id, sizeof(dev_id));
    memcpy(buf + 8, &timestamp, sizeof(timestamp));
    memcpy(buf + 12, &msg_type, sizeof(msg_type));
    memcpy(buf + 13, &g_msg_num, sizeof(g_msg_num));
    memcpy(buf + 14, &msg, sizeof(msg));

    uint16_t crc = CalculateCrc16((uint8_t*)buf, sizeof(DevSettingMsg) + 14);
    memcpy(buf + sizeof(buf) - 2, &crc, 2);

    std::string str(buf, sizeof(buf));

    // send str to serial port or other end points...
}
```

1. Is there any better way to implement this kind of protocols with C or C++?
2. If I want to keep my C++ code in C++ style (i.e. use C++ STL only, no memcpy, no & for variable address), what's the equivalent of above C, C++ mixed code in C++ only?

Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't be using memcpy for any of this except the actual message payload. The rest are in fixed locations, with fixed sizes, and frankly could be assembled by hand, octet by octet. As a bonus, you also get to control platform endian expectations (which you should be doing regardless, yet I see no evidence nor effort to do so here).

Comment: at least ensure that byte ordering of your machine is consistent with byte ordering of the protocol (ie: how 2 bytes numbers are encoded?).

Comment: What is "serial"? The nature of the protocol depends on what actual bus you are using: UART, SPI, CAN etc. Also your protocol spec is incomplete since it doesn't specify _network endianess_, which it must do to be useful.

Answer (score 2):

The binary communication protocols are notorious for requiring lots of error-prone boilerplate code. I strongly recommend looking into existing libraries and/or code generation solutions, the [CommsChampion Ecosystem](https://commschamp.github.io/) could be a good fit.

Answer (score 1):

### I recommend *documenting* your protocol as well as possible.

The [X11 protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System_core_protocol) specification could be inspirational.

Did you consider re-using some *existing communication protocol* e.g. [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) ? Do you care about communication between heterogenous systems and machines with different [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) and word sizes (e.g. a [RaspberryPI](https://raspberrypi.org/) communicating with an [Arduino](https://arduino.cc/) or a Linux/PowerPC or a Linux/x86-64 server)?

You could use C++ code generators like [SWIG](http://swig.org/), or C code generators like [RPCGEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPCGEN), or in some cases write your own C++ code generator (perhaps with the help of [GNU m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/m4.html) or of [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp) or [GNU autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/))

You may use (or adapt) existing C++ frameworks like [VMIME](https://www.vmime.org/) (which implement mail related protocols)

You could use existing Web service protocols (HTTP like) with libraries like [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) or [Wt](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt).